# Access props sent to components along with Redux state data

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, state

Normally you can access props sent by parent to child on child component. But when redux is used on child components the props sent by parent is lost with use of 'connect' method which maps redux state with components props.

E.g.:

Declaring a component with properties:
`<A_Component prop1='1' prop2='2' />`

Accessing without redux on child component, works fine:
`this.props.prop1` or `this.props.prop2`

Same statements will give `undefined` error if redux states are used.

Comment: Could you provide some code?

Answer (score 43, accepted):

Own component props are available as second argument of `mapStateToProps` function:

```js
// ParentComponent.js

// ... other component methods ...
render() {
  return <TodoContainer id="1" />
}

// TodoContainer.js

// `ownProps` variable contains own component props
function mapStateToProps(state, ownProps) {
  return {
    todo: state.todos[ownProps.id]
  };
}
```

Comment: after using `react-redux` for years today i came to know `mapStateToProps` is called on every dispatch.

Answer (score 9):

react-redux [connect method](https://react-redux.js.org/api/connect#connect) passes props to the wrapped element. The connect method can receive 3 methods:

- `mapStateToProps` - create the data props
- `mapDispatchToProps` - create the actions props
- `mergeProps` - combine the props produced by the 2 previous methods,
  and adds the parent assign props (ownProps / parentProps).

Usually you only override the `mapStateToProps` and or `mapDispatchToProps`, and you use the default `mergeProps` (`defaultMergeProps`).

This is the definition of `defaultMergeProps` method:

```
const defaultMergeProps = (stateProps, dispatchProps, parentProps) => ({
  ...parentProps, // ownProps
  ...stateProps, // mapStateToProps
  ...dispatchProps // mapDispatchToProps
})
```

So unless you override `defaultMergeProps` by your own `mergeProps` method, you'll always get the props assigned by the parent.

btw - both `mapStateToProps` and `mapDispatchToProps` receive ownProps as well, so they can combine them with the state, and create new data props / actions props.